# How to make a file name and a set extension

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string name;
  cout<<"What would you like new html file to be named?"<<endl;
  getline(cin,name);
  cout<<"Creating New Html File...Moment."<<endl;
  ofstream myfile (name);
  if(myfile.is_open())
  {                
  }
}
```

I need to make myfile with a .html extension can somebody tell me how or write me a code?

Comment: The content of this question needs to be reformatted.

Comment: Don't you need an 'int' in front of 'main()'?  G++ with no warnings permits it, but add -Wall and it will say "ISO C++ forbids declaration of `main' with no type".

Answer (score 8):

```
string name;
cout<<"What would you like new html file to be named?"<<endl;
getline(cin,name);
cout<<"Creating New Html File...Moment."<<endl;

name+=".html"; // the crucial ommision?

ofstream myfile (name);
```

Comment: Probably sensible to check that the given name does not itself end with ".html" so you do not create "file.html.html".

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add `.html` to the end of the file name:

```
name.append(".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to take into account the possibility that the filename entered by the user already ends in ".html" ? In that case, you can get the suffix with `name.substr(name.size()-5)`  - after you've checked that there are at least 6 characters in name, of course.